# positioning of text box and two column layout using htmll and css

Tags: html, css

I have to design a page such that there is a image on the top left.
A text box in the middle and then the page is partitioned into two columns.
A click event on partition1 changes the text on partition2.

As of now I have been able to insert the image and text box. 
How to position the text box in tme middle? Also, let me know how to partition a page into two columns such that click on 1 affects the output on column2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W2C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <html>
 <head>
<style> 
.newspaper {
-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
column-gap: 40px;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img alt="Twitter" src="twitter.jpeg" width="100" height="90"/>
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5">
Enter your comments here...
 </textarea><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


 </form>
 p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9</p>

<div class="newspaper">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam       nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css "left:" or "top:" to move it that many pixels from the top of the screen, or position it that many pixels from the left of the screen. For example:

height: 20px
width:20px
left:600px
top:0px

would style something at the top right of the screen because it 600px away from the left and 0px away from the top. You need to use a scripting language or an a tag for the button.